# CryptStringToBinary API behavior

Tags: c++, string, cryptography

I am seeing a strange behavior with **[CryptStringToBinary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptstringtobinaryw)** Cryptography API.

Please see the below code (config: x64 Debug):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
void main()
{
    DWORD dwSkip;
    DWORD dwFlags;
    DWORD dwDataLen;
    //LPCWSTR pszInput = L"jAAAAAECAAADZgAAAKQAAGdnNL1l56BWGFjDGR3RpxTQqqn6DAw3USv2eMkJYm4t";  //this works fine

    LPCWSTR pszInput = L"MyTest"; //doesnt work, API returns false,error code 0x0000000d
    
 
    // Determine the size of the BYTE array and allocate memory.
    if(! CryptStringToBinary(
        pszInput, 
        _tcslen( pszInput ) + 1, 
        CRYPT_STRING_BASE64,
        NULL, 
        &dwDataLen,
        &dwSkip, 
        &dwFlags ) )
    {
        DWORD dw = GetLastError(); //0x0000000d: The data is invalid
    
        throw std::exception( "Error computing Byte length." );
    }
 
    BYTE *pbyteByte = NULL;
    try
    {
        pbyteByte = new BYTE[ dwDataLen ];
        if( !pbyteByte ) 
        {
            DWORD m_dwError = ERROR_INVALID_DATA;
            
            throw std::exception( "Wrong array size." );
        }
    }
    catch( std::exception &ex )
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        
        throw std::exception( "Out of memory." );
    }
    
    return ;
}
```

With first `pszInput` string (commented string above), the **CryptStringToBinary** returns `true`. But if i use `L"MyTest"` as `pszInput` string it returns `false` with error code `0x0000000`.

I do see, there is some issue with length of the string passed to the API. When I pass the length without null terminated char (`removed+1`), the API returns `true` always. But in this case, is the `BYTE` length returned correct?

Could anybody help me understanding the reason behind this behavior?

Also, is my usage of the length parameter in API is correct?

Comment: CryptStringToBinary cchString (the 2nd) parameter has NOT to include terminating NULL character, so it must be _tcslen( pszInput ) and not _tcslen( pszInput ) + 1 See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380285.aspx for details.

Comment: Accepted!, However, the reason i used + 1 because CryptStringToBinary function usage in WinCrypt.h, it says strlen() + 1, see below:
//If cchString is 0, then pszString is NULL terminated and
// cchString is obtained via strlen() + 1.

Comment: Eh, before I start viewing the code, is this issue resolved?

Comment: @owlstead: Part of the issues is resolved.I am using CRYPT_STRING_BASE64 encoding and i am passing L"MyTest" which is not a base-64 coded string.for this i think the code is behavior is correct. But for other part length, which i am passing as + 1, I am not sure whether to pass + 1 or not. Could you plz provide your suggestion on this regard. Got confused why API works for both the input strings when i remove +1 in length parameter.Thanks

Comment: I guess it depends if you want to include the \0 in the plaintext...

Answer (score 2):

You need to have as input a base64 string as defined by the flag CRYPT_STRING_BASE64 
and L"MyTest" is not base64 while the first string is.

Examples of input formats :
http://pkix2.sysadmins.lv/library/html/T_PKI_ManagedAPI_CryptEncoding.htm

Comment: Would you please elaborate a little bit more your answer?

Comment: CryptStringToBinary(
        pszInput, /*input needs to be in the format defined by flag CRYPT_STRING_BASE64 */
        _tcslen( pszInput ), /* this is the length of the string no need to add 
+ 1*/ 
        CRYPT_STRING_BASE64,
        NULL, 
        &dwDataLen,
        &dwSkip, 
        &dwFlags )

Comment: From Review: Please [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51473150/edit) your answer and add those details to it. Please avoid commenting your own answer. Thank you.